Lower part of view disappears
I'm new to Blender. Lower part of my view is not visible. If I zoom to object it disappears. I couldn't find a solution to this from web. Can you help me?




View > Clip Start is probably too high for your scene. It doesn't show anything closer than Clip Start distance from view.

Thank you Lutzi for a rapid answer! That solved the problem. I guess I added high value to Clip Start from YouTube video.

Your welcome :) One of those things you can't know when you start with Blender. Clip Start should be as high as possible, End as low as possible, but most of the time the default range works.
